# Mapping keypad separate from keybaord numbers xcode OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, mapping, keyboard-events, keypad

I'm writing an application for OSx in xcode and am trying to get the numpad keys to be mapped differently than normal. For example the 7, 8, and 9 keys need to become 1, 2, and 3. also the clear and = need to be mapped to space and the period needs to become a forward slash. The only problem is I have tried mapping the numbers and it works but the numbers above the letter keys respond the same. I need those keys to become separate values. I have also attempted to map it by hard code and it still hasn't worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the key code out of the `NSEvent` (using `-[NSEvent keyCode]`) and use that rather than the character. The numbers on the keypad will have a different key code than the numbers above the letters.

Comment: I've attempted to do that here and a separate way in the second one -  `[_unoB setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:0x59];[_dosB setKeyEquivalent:@"#2"];`

Comment: Under the cocoa event keybinding section they say that # signifies the numpad

Comment: I don't understand - are you using this with buttons? You haven't fully described what you're trying to do, I don't think. Can you describe in more detail what you've got?

Comment: Sorry I am making a virtual keyboard that needs the numbers on the numpad reversed when pressed (7 key is a 1, 8 key is a 2, etc). It will be used on a touchscreen as well as with a physical keyboard (based on customer wishes). Basically I'm looking how to differentiate between the two numbers and have they numbers perform different actions. I hope that helps describe it a little better.